# Sequence defined by polynomial recursion

Tags: sequences-and-series, recursion

I'm struggling with a sequence that is defined by recursion, and that looks like : 
n<sub>t+1</sub> = n<sub>t</sub> + C/n<sub>t</sub> where C is a constant. 
How should I proceed to find the general formula for any term n<sub>t</sub>, depending on n<sub>0</sub> and t ?

Comment: There's no general formula. It's possible to determine the asymptotic behavior as $t\rightarrow\infty$, but not much more. Without context (what do you want to do with $n_t$?), it's hard to help you.

Comment: Okay, thanks ! It was just a theorical question, there's nothing i'd actually like to do with n<sub>t</sub>.. Just wondering how to deal with this kind of sequence !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opening the sequence partially shows that
$$n_{t+1}=n_t+\frac{C}{n_t}=n_{t-1}+\frac{C}{n_{t-1}}+\frac{C}{n_t}=n_{t-2}+\frac{C}{n_{t-2}}+\frac{C}{n_{t-1}}+\frac{C}{n_{t}}+\dots$$
$$\dots=n_0+C\sum_{k=0}^t\frac{1}{n_k}$$
where $n_0$ is some initial value $c_0$. Also assuming that $\sum_{k=0}^t\frac{1}{n_k}$ is limited.

**EDIT:** General formula is still unknown, since closed form for the sum does not exists. On the other hand, value of arbitrary (limited) $n_t$ is easily computed with program of several codelines if $C$ and $n_0$ are defined.

Comment: Thanks for the answer ! However it is still a recursive definition, isn't it ? I mean, I'd like to have a formula that directly calculates n<sub>t</sub>, without having to calculate all the previous terms ! I don't know if it's possible for this kind of sequence.

Comment: Yes, it still is recursive. The serie $\sum_{k=0}^t\frac{1}{n_k}$ does not have exact formula so we can only get further by approximations. (Atleast with my knowledge)

Comment: Alright ! Thanks a lot